# Traveling on Polish tourist visa while waiting for Swedish residence permit

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, sweden, cost-of-living, application-status

I am waiting for my decision of Swedish residence permit inside Sweden where I am allowed to live until I get a decision, but I want to travel using a Polish tourist visa in and out of the Schengen Zone.

Is it a legal plan?

Comment: What type is your Polish visa? Are you still in the possession of your passport while your residence permit application in Sweden is processed? What is your nationality? Flagging as unclear until you specify.